# Bash - How to remove any empty spaces around an equal sign

Tags: bash

I have an xml file which I'm trying to minimise using a bash script.

After removing any indentation, some part of the file looks like this:

```
<layer name       ="dotted_line"
align      ="topleft"
edge       ="topleft"
handcursor ="false"
keep       ="true"
url        ="%SWFPATH%/include/info_btn/dotted_line.png"
zorder     ="15"
/>
```

I'd like to remove any empty spaces before and after the equal sign, so it'd look like:

```
<layer name="dotted_line"
align="topleft"
edge="topleft"
handcursor="false"
keep="true"
url="%SWFPATH%/include/info_btn/dotted_line.png"
zorder="15"
/>
```

Any ideas how can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: It will be very difficult to exclude equal signs that might occur in attribute values without using a proper XML parser.

Comment: @RafaelGP: I know you found a solution, but please have a look at my answer:  xmllint will parse correctly every xml files, and get rid of more than just those extra spaces around name=value...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sed -i s/\ *=\ */=/g filename`

Regards

Comment: If there are other whitespace characters, e.g. Tabs, use `[[:space:]]*` instead of `\ *`

Comment: Why using cat? you already specify `-i` which means it will edit the file in place, so you can do a `sed -i ... file`

Comment: sed -i 's/\ *=\ */=/g' filename did the trick. Thank you very much! Knocked 3Kb down only with that line!

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
sed 's/\s*=\s*/=/g' inputFile
```

Comment: @chepner ... Good catch with the word `around` (= sign). :)

Comment: there should be a `g` at the end of sed command, otherwise it will break substitution at first occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

use `tr`?

```
$ echo 'hello there' | tr -d "[:space:]"
hellothere
$
```

Of course this'll trash ALL spaces in the file, which may be a bit too much.

Comment: instead of sed , tr is a much better and easy option .... the -s option is more suitable here with translate , it will supress the multiple occurence of the space to one . +1 for the answer @Marc

Comment: it will be too much : for example it will make "<tag something="foo" someotherthing="bar"/> become <tagsomething="foo"someotherthing="bar"/>, not only breaking the syntax but also changing the XML meaning itself ...

Comment: @Marc B , i did went ahead and make the edit in your answer ..... may be i should have waited

Answer (score 1):

You should first try to see if xmllint --format isn't already doing everything you need:

```
xmllint --format OLDFILE.xml > NEWFILE.xml
```

The big advantage of this approach:

- it will strip down every "cosmetic" things (extra spaces, etc). Ie it will not only replace `name   = value` with `name=value` but will get rid of many other extra spaces, and indent "neatly" and tersely.
- it knows XML, and therefore is much safer to use than any thing based on regular expressions (you CAN'T parse every xml files with regular expressions! It will work for basic xml structures, but is far from encomassing every thing an XML file can contain)

another way, if you are SURE that the name    ="value"  are each alone on their own line:

```
export _tab_="$(printf '\011')"
sed -e "s/^[ ${_tab_}]*[a-zA-Z0-9_-]\([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*\)[ ${_tab_}][ ${_tab_}]*=[ ${_tab_}][ ${_tab_}]*/\1=/"  OLDFILE.xml > NEWFILE.xml
```